# NIFI accessing Content Claim Identifier using Groovy

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to generate a unique id each time my process runs. My process starts with GetSFTP processor.

I was thinking of using flowfile's Content Claim Identifier for this purpose.

How do access this using Groovy? Thanks in advance!

[Flow File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM4Yc.png)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can depend on the flowfile `uuid` attribute being unique. Each flowfile in the system generates this on creation, so the flowfiles coming from `GetSFTP` will have this attribute populated and unique. To access the `uuid` attribute from Groovy (in a script or custom processor), use the code `flowfile.uuid` or `flowfile.getAttribute('uuid')`.

The content claim identifier is definitely *not* unique -- it is a reference to a specific location on the file system (or other storage media if configured) referencing the content bytes of the flowfile. Many flowfiles can have the same content claim identifier.

You can also generate a unique identifier using the [`UUID()`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#uuid) function in Apache NiFi Expression Language and put this in an attribute or content as needed using interpolation (i.e. `${UUID()}`).

Comment: I added a property called myId with the value ${UUID()} as suggested. But it gives me the following error:
'Myid' validated against '${UUID()}' is invalid because 'Myid' is not a supported property or has no Validator associated with it.

Comment: Also, the reason I can't use flowfile.uuid is because my GetSFTP can contain many flowfiles, but I am looking for a unique id every time my template is run.